# ObjectInputStream and socket timeout

Tags: java, sockets, jboss7.x, objectinputstream

I have a series of objects that are sent over a network socket.

The code for reading the data is already implemented and kind of works, but my problem is that sometimes the socket timeout cuts the read (`ObjectInputStream.readObject()`) of an object, corrupting the stream.

I use a timeout because this reading is performed within a JBoss resource adapter, so I don't want it to block indefinitely and potentially disable undeployment or graceful stopping of the EAR.

Is there a graceful (interruptible) way of handling reading object streams without using a separate thread and forcefully killing it?

P.S. I am aware that using object streams is a very bad decision, but that's just how the client applications are sending the data, and I can't change that.

Comment: Socket timeouts do not 'corrupt the stream'. What's your *real* problem?

Comment: From the documentation of `ObjectInputStream.readObject()`: _Exceptions are thrown for problems with the InputStream and for classes that should not be deserialized. All exceptions are fatal to the InputStream and leave it in an indeterminate state; it is up to the caller to ignore or recover the stream state._

Comment: @EJP What I meant by 'corrupting the stream' is that I suspect that if a timeout occurs while reading an object, that object will not be read completely and reinitializing the `ObjectInputStream` at that point is hopeless. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have something like this.

```
private volatile boolean closed = false;
private Closable/*e.g. ObjectOutputStream */ onClose = ...;


public void close() {
    closed = true;
    try {
        if (onCLose != null) onClose.close();
    } catch(IOException ignored) {
    }
}


private Object readObject() {
    try {
         if (closed) throw new IllegalStateException();
         return steam.readObject();
    } finally {
         if (closed) throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate please? Are you suggesting that I read the stream on a separate thread (without a timeout) and then just close its socket on the main thread when I wish to stop it?